# Error in manifest file

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, manifest, eclipse-emf, emf

> Error "Bundle org.eclipse.emf.workspace cannot be resolved" in the
>   beginning of the line 
>   org.eclipse.emf.workspace;bundle-version="1.5.1",

Am I missing anything that is to be installed in my Eclipse Juno?
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you do not have EMF installed.  Go to Help -> Install new software... In the Work with text box, choose the Juno update site.  In the list that appears, choose EMF.  And follow the instructions to install.